# AttributeError: First letter of class name <mytodo.kv> is in lowercase

Tags: python, kivymd

I am new to both Python and KivyMD. I am working on a personal project which is a ToDo app.
I have a main.py and helpers.py(for styles) and my app was running(just have few buttons and text fields for now). Now I moved the styles to .kv file. When I run I see the following error:
raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: First letter of class name <mytodo.kv> is in lowercase

**Main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MyToDo(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Amber"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
        
        return Builder.load_string('mytodo.kv')
        
    def add_task_high(self):
        print("Save the task as severity 1 in the DB and show in list")

    def call(self, obj):
        if obj.icon == "priority-high":
            self.add_task_high()
        elif obj.icon == "priority-low":
            print("Save the task as severity 2 in the DB")
        else:
            print("Mark the task as done in the DB")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyToDo().run()
```

**mytodo.kv**

```
MDTextField:
    id: textfield
    hint_text: 'Add Task'
    font_size: 15
    required: True
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.2, 'center_y': 0.1}
    size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
    multiline: True

MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
    data: {'Top Priority': 'priority-high', 'Low Priority': 'priority-low', 'Accomplished': 'check'}
    rotation_root_button: True
    callback: app.call

MDFloatingActionButton:
    icon: 'priority-high'
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .2, "center_y": .9}
    size_hint_x: None
    width: 200
```

Comment: I don't know anything about kivy, but it seems the error message is complaining that the file name `mytodo.kv` doesn't match the capitalization of the class name `MyToDo`.  Have you tried renaming the file so that the capitalization is the same?

Comment: Yes, I tried MyToDo.ky but it didn't work.

Comment: `.ky` or `.kv`?

Comment: The GUI styles are written in .kv file.

Comment: Did you also update the filename in `return Builder.load_string('mytodo.kv')`?

Comment: Yes, that didn't help. I also tried:  return Builder.load_file('mytodo.kv'). Now getting a dark screen. No buttons/text field are shown on the app screen. I think I am missing the part where I need to pack the screen with buttons/text field. But I am unable to figure out how to do that part.

Comment: The mytodo.kv file was missing FloatLayout: I can see the buttons n text fields now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `load_string` in your Python code, you should use `load_file`. As in:

```
class MyToDo(MDApp):

def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Amber"
    self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "A700"
    
    return Builder.load_file('mytodo.kv') #Replaced load_string with load_file
....
```